# Suggestion: Multiple reputation gain options to tag edits

Tags: discussion

When you edit a tag, you get two points, no matter much work or lack of work you put into it. I propose that there should be an option for moderators to award additional reputation for especially good, detailed tag edits as an inncentive to eliminate twenty character non-descriptive tag edits. Does anyone disagree/agree? Leave a comment and say why.

Comment: After a certain amount of reputation gained from edits, you stop getting rep for them entirely.

Comment: How many edits is that?

Comment: @William Specifically, for tag wiki edits, you'll stop gaining reputation once you can make them without needing approval. This [privilege](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/trusted-user) can only be obtained with 20000 reputation. So, only the super-dedicated would probably need to worry about that.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 That's not what I mean. [After earning 1000 rep through suggested edits, you stop earning it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82020/why-theres-a-limit-on-edits-reputation-reward) Granted, this may only be for edits to questions and answers, but often tag wiki edits are treated the same as other edits (e.g. for badges and such).

Comment: Okay, I did not know about the 1000 rep cap. Thanks for informing me. I just made this as a suggestion to create incentive for detailed tag edits.

Comment: @root45 I'm not sure what you're trying to get at. For example, I am well over 1000 reputation and I still get +2 reputation whenever I have a suggested tag wiki edit approved, despite the fact that I no longer get reputation for question/answer edits. William's question was clearly about the reputation from tag wiki edits, which was the specific type of edit I was responding to. In general, it just seems that you can only earn reputation for edits you had to suggest; those you can make immediately without approval due to certain privileges don't earn rep anymore, but others still do.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Did you read the link I included? I'm not talking about your total reputation level, I'm talking about the total reputation you receive from suggested edits. [This is straight from the FAQ.](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation) "You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through suggested edits."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it should be a moderator only feature.

Something like the bounty system for answers could work here as well. If a user thinks that a tag wiki edit deserves more reputation then they can award it much like answer bounties but with a lower step range.

Comment: I agree completely. i think people who spend time making detailed tag wiki edits deserve more reputation.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think we (the moderators) should ever have the power to award reputation.

Personally, I find a 20 character tag wiki much better than a 0 character one. :) Though I agree, they don't get as much attention as they deserve, both in the form of editors and readers.

Comment: Yes, but I think a little incentive to do better than a twenty character edit.